# SSRS 2005 - dynamically assigning a 'jump to report' name in a textbox

Tags: reporting-services

I'm using SSRS 2005 and I'd like to be able to 'jump to' different reports depending on the value in a date field.  For example:

```
=iif(Fields!Date.Value = Today, TodaysReport, OtherDaysReport)
```

When I use this syntax, I get this error when previewing the report:

> The ReportName expression for the textbox ‘CallId’ contains an error: [BC30451] Name 'TodaysReport' is not declared.

I don't get any error on the 'OtherDaysReport' parameter but I think the compiler gave up on the first error.

Is the syntax I'm using in the `IIF` statement valid in a 'Jump to Report' expression in the Navigation property of a textbox?  If not, is there a different way to do what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you found answer to your problem yet. but for anybody with similar problem please try following

put your report names in quotations. In your case try

```
=iif(Fields!Date.Value = Today,"TodaysReport", "OtherDaysReport")
```

Also make sure you specify the right parameters and the "Omit" properties as required.